# Convert an object to System Guid

Tags: c#

```
Guid mainfolderid = (main.GetValue(""));
```

where `main` is a dynamic entity.

How can I convert the above mentioned `main.GetValue("")` to `System.Guid`?

The error says

> Cannot implicitly convert type object to 'System.Guid'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Does the `GetValue` method actually return a `Guid` typed as `object`? If so, then you just need to perform an explicit cast like so:

```
Guid mainfolderid = (Guid)main.GetValue("");
```

If not, does `GetValue` return something that can be passed to one of the constructors (ie, a `byte[]` or `string`)? In that case you could do this:

```
Guid mainfolderid = new Guid(main.GetValue(""));
```

If neither of the above are applicable then you're going to need to do some manual work to convert whatever's returned by `GetValue` to a `Guid`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .Net 4.0, there were Parsing methods added to the Guid struct:

```
Guid Guid.Parse(string input)
```

and

```
bool Guid.TryParse(string input, out Guid result)
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
Guid mainfolderid = new Guid(main.GetValue("").ToString());
```

Comment: Wrong. [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) takes no arguments.

Comment: Doesn't work if main.GetValue("") is of type Object. The Guid constructor doesn't take an Object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the GUID constructor, and pass it a string representation of the GUID. This will work if the object is really a string representation of GUID. Example:

```
Guid mainfolderid = new Guid(main.GetValue("").ToString());
```

Comment: This compiles. But I wouldn't call it "fool-proof". It only works in a very narrow range of cases. Wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid mainfolderid = (Guid)(main.GetValue(""));
```

Comment: It still says The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type(System.Guid is a non nullable type)

Comment: @dtb You must have saw that before I edited.  I caught myself on that one :)

Comment: @Ashutosh, yes, see my edit now.  Also, if the GetValue method is returning a string representation of a Guid rather than an actual Guid, you will want to use Dustin's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) could be [constructed by string representation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx), so this should work:

```
Guid result = new Guid(main.GetValue("").ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a solution using the Type of the objet:

```
GuidAttribute   guidAttr;
object[]        arrAttrs;
Type            type;
string          strGuid;

type = main.GetType();
arrAttrs = type.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute), false);
guidAttr = (arrAttrs != null && arrAttrs.Length > 0) ? arrAttrs[0] as GuidAttribute: null;
if (guidAttr != null) {
    strGuid = "{" + guidAttr.Value.ToUpper() + "}";
}
```

Comment: -1: WARNING: This will return the GUID of `typeof(main)` not a unique GUID for each instance of main, nor a unique GUID for each value returned by `main.GetValue()`.